# How to assign the position and size to a half colored circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

When trying to draw a half colored circle, I cant tell the script where to start to draw, since the custom command uses a coordinate in polar form to start drawing using

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\statcirc}{ O{#2} m }{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[#2] (0,0) circle (1.0ex); 
    \fill[#1] (0,0) -- (90:1.5ex) arc (90:270:1.5ex) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frametitle}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        En un diagrama de Venn se vería
                \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
                \filldraw[fill=blue!20, draw=blue!60] (-2,0) circle (1.5cm);
                \filldraw[fill=red!20, draw=red!60] (2,0) circle (1.5cm);
                \statcirc[orange]{green}
                \node at (-2,1.8) {$D_{f}=R$};
                \node at (2,1.8) {$C_{f}=R_{f}$};
                \node at (0,1.2) {$f$};
                \node at (0,-2) {\textcolor{blue}{some text}};
                \node (x1) at (-1.5,0) {};
                \node (x2) at (-1.15,-0.4) {};
                \node (y1) at (1,0.5) {};
                \node (y3) at (1,-0.5) {};
                \draw[->] (x1) -- (y1);
                
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{center}

\begin{document}
```

I cant adjust the part of

```
   \fill[#1] (0,0) -- (90:1.5ex) arc (90:270:1.5ex) -- cycle;
```

since if I use a extra argument (i.e. the circle center must be at (2,0)) the draw overlaps, get ignored or get broke like the next image
[image]
When the idea is that the circle half colored be ar right of the arrow and bigger

Comment: You are looking for a `pic`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a `pic` that does what your command would have done, but can be placed wherever you like. Also this avoids nesting `tikzpicture` environments. The usage is slightly different, it uses pgf keys, which control the colors and radii of the semicircles.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{pics/statcirc/.style={code={%
 \tikzset{statcirc/.cd,#1}
 \def\myvalue##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/statcirc/##1}}
 \fill[color/.expanded=\myvalue{color 1}] (90:\myvalue{r1}) 
    arc[start angle=90,end angle=270,radius=\myvalue{r1}]; 
 \fill[color/.expanded=\myvalue{color 2}] (90:\myvalue{r2}) 
    arc[start angle=90,end angle=-90,radius=\myvalue{r2}]; 
 }},statcirc/.cd,color 1/.initial=orange,color 2/.initial=green,
    r1/.initial=1ex,r2/.initial=1.5ex}
\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\statcirc}{ O{#2} m }{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[#2] (0,0) circle (1.0ex); 
    \fill[#1] (0,0) -- (90:1.5ex) arc (90:270:1.5ex) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frametitle}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,t]
  \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
   A Venn diagram
   \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
        \filldraw[fill=blue!20, draw=blue!60] (-2,0) circle[radius=1.5cm];
        \filldraw[fill=red!20, draw=red!60] (2,0) circle[radius=1.5cm];
        \path (2,0) pic[transform shape]{statcirc={r1=1.5cm,r2=1cm}};
        \node at (-2,1.8) {$D_{f}=R$};
        \node at (2,1.8) {$C_{f}=R_{f}$};
        \node at (0,1.2) {$f$};
        \node[text=blue]at (0,-2) {some text};
        \node (x1) at (-1.5,0) {};
        \node (x2) at (-1.15,-0.4) {};
        \node (y1) at (1,0.5) {};
        \node (y3) at (1,-0.5) {};
        \draw[->] (x1) -- (y1);                
    \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{center}
  \end{column}
%
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative for the `pic` proposed in another answer.

In this case `circle` paths have been replaced for circular nodes over which half filled circles are drawn with a `path picture` command.

All additional labels are placed using relative positioning with nodes names as references.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positionIning}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frametitle}
Another Venn diagram

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, minimum size=2.1cm, fill=blue!20, draw=blue!60, label={$D_f=R$}] (left) {};
\node[circle, minimum size=2.1cm, fill=red!20, draw=red!60, label={$C_f=R_f$}, right=0.7cm of left,
path picture={\fill[red!60] (path picture bounding box.north) rectangle (path picture bounding box.south west); \fill[green] (right.center) --++(90:0.7) arc[start angle=90, end angle=-90, radius=0.7cm]--cycle;}] (right) {};
\draw[->] ([xshift=-7mm]left.east)--([xshift=3mm]right.160);
\path (left.north)--(right.north) node [midway, below] {$f$};
\path (left.south)--(right.south) node [midway, below, blue] {some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]